# Most efficient way to store number 11.111 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What datatype is the most efficient to store a number such as 11.111.

The numbers will have up 2 digits before the point and up to three after.

Currently the column is a 'bigint', I am guessing that this will need to be changed to a decimal or a float.

Any help much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: does the representation need to be exact?

Comment: Hold on. How s that int? isnt it float? 11.111 is float no?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be exact to 3 points after the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bigint is an integer datatype, so yeah, that won't work without some preprocessing footwork.  Do you need to store the values precisely, or only approximately?  The binary floating point types (`float`, `real`) are efficient and compact, but don't represent many decimal values exactly, and so comparisons won't always give you what you expect, and errors accumulate.  `decimal` is a good bet.  A decimal of precision 5 and scale 3 (meeting your requirements) consumes five bytes.

See documentation on the decimal datatype [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), and datatypes in general [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).

Comment: Difficult for me to choose a correct answer, but I found this the most helpful. Maybe my question wording wasn't so great. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you need exact representation, the [**smallmoney**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) datatype uses 4 bytes.

This is equivalent to using an int (4 bytes), and performing multiplication/division to take care of the fractional digits.

Comment: Don't think it gets smaller than this

Answer (score 2):

I would think that you have two options: Multiply by 1000 and store as an int (and divide on the way out), or just store as a double.  With memory and drive space being so cheap, it's probably not worth the hassle of optimizing any further.

Comment: When you say a double you mean a float right? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the DECIMAL data type. It stores exact floating point numbers

```
DECLARE @d decimal(5, 3)
SET @d=12.671
SELECT @d, DATALENGTH(@d)
```

As @Mitch pointed out, this would be 5 bytes in size. You pay an extra byte for easier calculations with the value.

Comment: ..and that should be DECIMAL(5,3)

Answer (score 0):

Use the decimal data type to set exact precision:

```
decimal(5,3)
```